# What is the fastest way to move cursor to the end of a line by line number?

Tags: cursor-movement

I recently found out that you can move the cursor the beginning of a line quickly by line number like this:

```
:11
```

Regardless of your cursor position, this will move the cursor the **beginning** of line 11.

But what is the fastest way to move to the **end** of line 11?

Comment: fastest in User time or CPU (if you have a script that do thousands movements to end of lines) time?

Comment: You should probably clarify your usecase: `11G$`

Comment: `this will move the cursor the beginning of line 11` Only if `:set startofline`.

Comment: An even faster way to move to the start of the 11th line would be to use `11G` in normal mode. Not sure how to move to the end of line without scripting though...

Comment: @MaximKim Yes I think that is the answer, somehow forgotten that at the time of writing this question. But I guess there is no equivalent for `:lineNumber` that will move the cursor to the end of line?

Comment: If you really want to do it with an ex command you have `:11norm! $`

Comment: @statox That is good to know. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Maxime Kim a good way is: `11G$`